# Map JSON KEY as column names in INSERT QUERY

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure to insert these values into a table. Always my table column name will be the key and column data will be the value in the JSON.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'[
          {
            "name": "abcd",
            "id": 12,
            "feelings": {
              "happy": 0,
              "angry": 1,
              "sad": 1
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "abcdf",
            "id": 14,
            "feelings": {
              "happy": 0,
              "angry": 1,
              "sad": 1
            }
          }
        ]'

DECLARE @id INT;
DECLARE @last_name NVARCHAR(50);
SET @id =10;
SET @last_name = 'Mike'
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Table([name],[id],[lastname],[happy],[angry],[sad]) 
VALUES ("abcd",@id,@last_name,0,1,1)


How can I achieve this for any JSON format? Always the JSON key should be mapped to the column name. The insert statement should be able to insert all the entries from the JSON. Only the key inside the feelings will change. All others remain the same.
```

I need to include data from the JSON as well as static declared data in the insert query.Does OPENJSON allow including static data in WITH().

Please help me with this.

Comment: Does the table always have these two columns? As a note, the input JSON `[{"key1":"name1","key2",:"name2"}]` is not valid (`,` after the `"key2"`).

Comment: `INSERT` statements have to be well defined. You can't, in effect, have a statement that says "Insert the values of the elements into the same named columns"; that isn't how SQL works. You would need to write SQL for each table that reads the appropriate JSON. Otherwise you'd need to go down the Dynamic SQL route, which I don't suggest for someone that isn't familiar with SQL, nor understands the caveats that come with working with dynamic statements.

Comment: Have you already consulted [the documentation on the topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server)? What have you tried yourself? (P.S. Neither the JSON data, nor the SQL code in your question currently have valid syntax.)

Comment: Do the KEY fields within the feeling object change?  If so, change it to an array.  The other columns match the JSON document field names so they should convert to columns defined by WITH clause of OPENJSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that dynamic statement should be your first option:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'[
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "id": 12,
        "feelings": {
          "happy": 0,
          "angry": 1,
          "sad": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "abcdf",
        "id": 14,
        "feelings": {
          "happy": 0,
          "angry": 1,
          "sad": 1
        }
      }
]'
```

Statement:

```
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @schema nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @id int
SET @id = 10

SELECT 
   @columns = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([key]), N','),
   @schema = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME([key]), N' int ''$.feelings."', [key], '"'''), N',')
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$[0].feelings')

SELECT @stm = CONCAT(
   N'INSERT INTO InputTable ([id],[name],',
   @columns,
   N') SELECT @id,[name],',
   @columns,
   N' FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH ([name] varchar(100) ''$."name"'',',
   @schema,
   N')'
)

PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm, N'@json nvarchar(max), @id int', @json, @id
```

Generated dynamic statement:

```
INSERT INTO InputTable ([id],[name],[happy],[angry],[sad]) 
SELECT @id,[name],[happy],[angry],[sad] 
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   [name] varchar(100) '$."name"',
   [happy] int '$.feelings."happy"',
   [angry] int '$.feelings."angry"',
   [sad] int '$.feelings."sad"'
)
```

Comment: I don't know the column definitions..Column definitions can change and as per that the JSON will also change.Is there any way to fetch the key name from JSON for stored procedure?

Comment: version 12.0.It's Microsoft Azure SQL Database

Comment: [{
      "name": 3,
      "id": 4393,
      "feelings": {
        "happy": 0,
        "angry": 1,
        "sad": 1
      }
  },{},{}] In this JSON only the feeling JSON entries will change and the insert statement should include name and the feeling only.Example : insert into table (name,happy,angry)values("abcd","yes","yes","yes").@Zhorov  .How to exclude some keys?

Comment: Done.Please help me on the same

Comment: Is it possible to include a static value in the WITH() of FROM OPENJSON?I have a variable value SET @var1 = 20.I need to include this also as a column in insert statement

Comment: I have declared a variable with static int value  .I need to add this value in a column in the insert statement with each insert...Is it possible?..Which means the insert statement is not fetching all column and values from JSON...Some are static defined values

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this.  This opens and flattens the JSON

```
declare
  @json         nvarchar(max)=N'[
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "id": 12,
        "feelings": {
          "happy": 0,
          "angry": 1,
          "sad": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "abcdf",
        "id": 14,
        "feelings": {
          "happy": 0,
          "angry": 1,
          "sad": 1
        }
      }
    ]';

INSERT INTO Table([name],[happy],[angry],[sad])
select oj.[name], f.*
from openjson(@json) with (name        nvarchar(4000),
                           id          int,
                           feelings    nvarchar(max) as json) oj
cross apply
  openjson(oj.feelings) with (happy     int,
                              angry     int,
                              sad       int) f;
```

Results

```
name    id  happy   angry   sad
abcd    12  0       1       1
abcdf   14  0       1       1
```

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I got your question correctly, but if you need to get data from JSON based on columns existing in table which you want to pass by name then you need to have dynamic sql. So here's an example of how you can do it using [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql) view:

```
drop table if exists dbo.temp_data
create table dbo.temp_data (name nvarchar(128), happy bit, angry bit, sad bit);

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
declare @table_name nvarchar(256) = 'dbo.temp_data'
declare @data nvarchar(max) = '[
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "id": 12,
        "feelings": {
          "happy": 0,
          "angry": 1,
          "sad": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "abcdf",
        "id": 14,
        "feelings": {
          "happy": 0,
          "angry": 1,
          "sad": 1
        }
      }
    ]';

declare @stmt nvarchar(max);
declare @stmt_part1 nvarchar(max);
declare @stmt_part2 nvarchar(max);

select
    @stmt_part1 = concat(isnull(@stmt_part1 + ',', ''),c.name),
    @stmt_part2 = concat(isnull(@stmt_part2 + ',', ''),'json_value(o.value, ''$.feelings.',c.name,''')')
from sys.columns as c
where
    c.object_id = object_id(@table_name) and
    c.name <> 'name'

set @stmt = concat('
    insert into ',@table_name,' (name,',@stmt_part1,')
    select
        json_value(o.value, ''$.name'') as name,',@stmt_part2,'
    from openjson(@data) as o
');

exec sys.sp_executesql
    @stmt,
    N'@data nvarchar(max)',
    @data = @data;

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
select * from dbo.temp_data
```

I don't know which version of Sql Server you're using so I'm not sure if you can use [`string_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) system function so I've used pretty standard trick to aggregate column names into string.